# File server for Windows & Linux clients with LDAP authentication

Tags: linux, windows, samba, nfs, openldap

I am facing an issue with implementation planning,
currently using LDAP server & NFS
clients are mixed of windows & Linux, I need to implement a file sharing solution that will cater both windows & Linux clients with LDAP authentication (to be specific openLDAP) & file level permissions, I have searched about samba it does work on NTLM only or with Microsoft's Active Directory, unable to find out the solution

Comment: active directory is in the end just ldap + kerberos. You can absolutely join a Linux PC to AD, and run an AD based on linux servers!

Comment: yes I have done it in this way but here we don't wanna use windows servers

Comment: as said, you can do the same with Linux servers. OpenLDAP, kerberos, samba.

Answer (score 1):

Use Samba as an AD domain controller. If you want filesharing, there is only Samba, there are other things like freeipa, but they only give you authentication, no file sharing. Do not use Samba with an openldap backend (aka NT4-style domain controller or PDC), they rely on SMBv1, which is deprecated and will be removed.